# Class with both private as well as public constructor in C# can be instantiated - Strange

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, access-modifiers

Folks, I am just learning about constructors. I am wondering why MS is allowing both private as well as public constructor in a class. If I have both public and private constructor, it apparently fails the purpose of private constructor as in, it allows the creation of instance of the class outside. I find it strange. What I would expect is, if both private and public constructors are present in a class, it should be a compile time error.

Can someone please explain the usage with example and the reason.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with having both public and private constructors. One example follows.

It could be that three different public constructors share a large portion of initialization logic. Rather than repeating the same logic three times, it would make sense to have a private constructor that performs the common parts, and then have the public constructors delegate to the private constructor for the common parts.

This isn't the only use case, but it should be enough to convince you I hope.

Comment: No certainly I do not agree with this style and the paramount reason is, how it can allow instantiation outside the class which is against the very concept of the SPECIAL private constructor

Comment: @Divine I don't understand your question. A private constructor cannot be called from outside the class. So why is that against encapsulation?

Comment: My question is Class A { public A() { }; private A() { }; } Class B :A { A a = new A(); }. I say this is not possible when we have ONLY private cons, but when I have public and private, why it is possible? Why precedence is given to public cons? It defeats the purpose of private constructor that I dont want the class to be instantiated outside the class as you said.

Comment: @Divine I believe that code will give you a compiler error, because the two constructors for `A` have the same signature.

Comment: Oh thats right. Sorry. But even when I have some parameter for private cons, why would it allow instantiation outside the class? As per private constructor rubric, it shouldn't allow instantiation anywhere but inside the nested class right?

Comment: A particular constructor being marked private just means that ***that particular constructor*** cannot be called from outside the class. It says nothing about other constructors of the class.

Comment: Thank you Timothy. Well I will understand it still better with time. Bottomline is, I shouldn't be able to create an instance of the class which contains private constructor. That is what Microsoft document says. But here the behavior is different. Do you please understand my concern? I am sorry.

Comment: @Divine If you put a breakpoint in your private constructor, you'll see that it will never hit when instantiating your class (except when you actually call it from the public ctor, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

At first it initialize with public constructor and the private has no use. Compiler only look for public constructor so that it can be initialize outside the class. private Constructor is treated as normal method or we can say another version of constructor, also there must be some difference in constructors signature.

Answer (score 1):

No one ever gave you an example of a class with both public and private constructors so here is a simple example of where you could see one.

One situation that you may see is classes that have both public constructors and static methods that create an instance of the class that need to set special things inside the constructor.

Here is a example class, the field `_timeStamp` is [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which means it can only be set inside a constructor. When a user constructs the class he is forced to use the current time for the timestamp, the method `GetMessageFromFile(` uses a special private constructor that only it (and other methods inside the function) can call to be able to pass in a value for the timestamp.

```
public class TimeStampedMessage
{
    public TimeStampedMessage(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        _timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private TimeStampedMessage(string message, DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        Message = message;
        _timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public string TimeStampedMessage { get; private set; }

    //Because this field is marked readonly it must be set inside a constructor.
    private readonly DateTime _timeStamp;
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get { return _timeStamp; } }

    public static TimeStampedMessage GetMessageFromFile(string path)
    {
        var fileText = File.ReadAllText(path);
        var fileTimeStamp = File.GetCreationTime(path);

        //this constructor can not be used by a end user because it is marked private, but it can be used here inside the function.
        return new Foo(fileText, fileTimeStamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shortest pretty straight answer is
Both public and private constructors work in their own way.
How ?? look 
You have public constructor to instantiate from outside the class.
but now lets assume there might be few things that you want to do only when you call the constructor with in the same class. 

 So there is no confusion in this both will work at same time in their own way depending on requirement.